# How does one know the growth rate of distinct prime divisors?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

I saw online a statement that

"It can be shown that the number of distinct prime divisors of an integer n, denoted $\omega(n)$, is such that

$$\omega(n) = O\left(\frac{\log n}{\log \log n}\right)."$$

But I really have no idea how this is true,

In general I actually have very little experience proving any results about growth rates and such.

Does one need to  use some basic known results in number theory to prove it?

Comment: You need to know a lot more than basic results in number theory to prove things of this kind. You can see some of the results and ideas at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_number_theory

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The smallest number with $m$ distinct prime factors is the primorial $M=p_1\cdot\ldots\cdot p_m$.
By the prime number theorem $\sum_{p\leq x}\log p= x+o(x)$ and $p_m\approx m\log m$, hence in order to have $\omega(M)=m$ we need $M\geq e^{m\log m+O(m)}$ and that turns into
$$ \omega(M)=O\left(\frac{\log M}{\log\log M}\right) $$
as wanted.

Comment: Can you please explain the following:   I understand why if you write $M$ as you did that we would need  $\omega(M)=m$, but I am not sure how you do some of the steps ( I am very new to this subject) such as, how did you get the estimate with the little o? and why in order for us to have that do you require M to be greater then that term and how does that turn into the big O notation form?

Comment: @Quality: both the estimates $\sum_{p\leq x}\log p=x+o(x)$ and $p_m\approx m\log m$ follow from the prime number theorem. The remaining part is trivial: we want an upper bound for $\omega$, hence we may equivalently find how small $M$ might be to ensure $\omega(M)=m$.

Comment: Thank you.. so I see from the prime number theorem that $\Pi (x)$ is asymptotic to $x/logx$ and so the some of the primes over the logs gives me the x, where does the o(x) come from though?

Comment: @Quality: the remainder term in the prime number theorem depends on the distribution of the zeroes of the Riemann $\zeta$ function. Assuming RH, such $o(x)$ is indeed $O(\sqrt{x}\log^2 x)$, but the PNT is enough to ensure $\psi(x)\sim x$, i.e. $\psi(x) = x+o(x)$.

Comment: I understand that part now, I really do appreciate the time. The last things I would be wondering are, how do you get the bound on the mth prime? and isnt \omega(M)=m by your definition of M? Why does it require that extra part and is it actually equivalent to the last part?

Comment: @Quality: both your questions have the same answer. By inversion, we get that the PNT in the form $\psi(x)\sim x$ or $\pi(x)\sim\frac{x}{\log x}$ gives $p_n\sim n\log n$. And always by inversion, if we get a lower bound for a number with $\omega=$(some constant) we also get an upper bound for $\omega(n)$.

Answer (score 2):

This problem is unusual in that there is an obvious sequence, [the primorials,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primorial) for which the value of $\omega(n)$ increases; your function does not increase (achieve a new maximum) at anywhere else. So, it is enough to estimate the inverse function. Let me make a quick program output, give me a few minutes. It appears that, for $n > 2,$ we get
$$ \omega(n) < 1.4 \frac{\log n}{\log \log n}. $$
Alright, he does not attempt an explicit bound such as my conjectured 1.4, but [Ramanujan does derive the maximal order](http://ramanujan.sirinudi.org/Volumes/published/ram35.pdf). 
Note that this extreme behavior is not at all typical, [see Erdos Kac](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s%E2%80%93Kac_theorem). Again, Ramanujan did get part of Erdos-Kac.

Page 17 of Carella. See formula (4.6) which gives an explicit error term. 
[image]

```
  omega prime             n = primorial              log n / log log n  ratio
    1    2                                          2    -1.89119  -0.528766
    2    3                                          6    3.0723  0.650978
    3    5                                         30    2.77847  1.07973
    4    7                                        210    3.18934  1.25418
    5   11                                       2310    3.7835  1.32153
    6   13                                      30030    4.41897  1.35778
    7   17                                     510510    5.10235  1.37192
    8   19                                    9699690    5.79097  1.38146
    9   23                                  223092870    6.50283  1.38401
   10   29                                 6469693230    7.24626  1.38002
   11   31                               200560490130    7.98531  1.37753
   12   37                              7420738134810    8.74464  1.37227
   13   41                            304250263527210    9.50917  1.3671
   14   43                          13082761331670030    10.2687  1.36336
   15   47                         614889782588491410    11.0328  1.35959
   16   53                       32589158477190044730    11.8079  1.35502
   17   59                     1922760350154212639070    12.592  1.35006
   18   61                   117288381359406970983270    13.3715  1.34614
   19   67                  7858321551080267055879090    14.1585  1.34195
   20   71                557940830126698960967415390    14.9465  1.3381
   21   73              40729680599249024150621323470    15.7307  1.33497
   22   79            3217644767340672907899084554130    16.5207  1.33166
   23   83          267064515689275851355624017992790    17.3116  1.32859
   24   89        23768741896345550770650537601358310    18.1072  1.32544
   25   97      2305567963945518424753102147331756070    18.9107  1.32201
  omega prime             n = primorial              log n / log log n  ratio
```

I let the primorials get bigger but did not print them, the 1.4 figure looks good.

```
    1    2    -1.89119  -0.528766
    2    3    3.0723  0.650978
    3    5    2.77847  1.07973
    4    7    3.18934  1.25418
    5   11    3.7835  1.32153
    6   13    4.41897  1.35778
    7   17    5.10235  1.37192
    8   19    5.79097  1.38146
    9   23    6.50283  1.38401
   10   29    7.24626  1.38002
   11   31    7.98531  1.37753
   12   37    8.74464  1.37227
   13   41    9.50917  1.3671
   14   43    10.2687  1.36336
   15   47    11.0328  1.35959
   16   53    11.8079  1.35502
   17   59    12.592  1.35006
   18   61    13.3715  1.34614
   19   67    14.1585  1.34195
   20   71    14.9465  1.3381
   21   73    15.7307  1.33497
   22   79    16.5207  1.33166
   23   83    17.3116  1.32859
   24   89    18.1072  1.32544
   25   97    18.9107  1.32201
   26  101    19.7141  1.31885
   27  103    20.5143  1.31616
   28  107    21.3147  1.31365
   29  109    22.1122  1.31149
   30  113    22.9101  1.30947
   31  127    23.722  1.3068
   32  131    24.5336  1.30433
   33  137    25.3474  1.30191
   34  139    26.1586  1.29976
   35  149    26.9763  1.29744
   36  151    27.7914  1.29537
   37  157    28.6082  1.29333
   38  163    29.4267  1.29134
   39  167    30.2448  1.28948
   40  173    31.0644  1.28765
   41  179    31.8853  1.28586
   42  181    32.7042  1.28424
   43  191    33.5277  1.28252
   44  193    34.3491  1.28097
   45  197    35.1701  1.27949
   46  199    35.9893  1.27816
   47  211    36.8141  1.27668
   48  223    37.6441  1.2751
   49  227    38.4735  1.2736
   50  229    39.3011  1.27223
   51  233    40.1283  1.27092
   52  239    40.9563  1.26965
   53  241    41.7826  1.26847
   54  251    42.6121  1.26724
   55  257    43.4424  1.26604
   56  263    44.2734  1.26487
   57  269    45.105  1.26372
   58  271    45.9351  1.26265
   59  277    46.7659  1.2616
   60  281    47.5962  1.2606
   61  283    48.4251  1.25968
   62  293    49.2567  1.25871
   63  307    50.0927  1.25767
   64  311    50.9283  1.25667
   65  313    51.7624  1.25574
   66  317    52.5962  1.25484
   67  331    53.434  1.25388
   68  337    54.2722  1.25294
   69  347    55.1124  1.25199
   70  349    55.9513  1.25109
   71  353    56.7898  1.25022
   72  359    57.6287  1.24938
   73  367    58.4686  1.24853
   74  373    59.3089  1.2477
   75  379    60.1495  1.24689
   76  383    60.9897  1.24611
   77  389    61.8302  1.24535
   78  397    62.6717  1.24458
   79  401    63.5127  1.24385
   80  409    64.3548  1.24311
   81  419    65.1984  1.24236
   82  421    66.0409  1.24165
   83  431    66.885  1.24094
   84  433    67.728  1.24025
   85  439    68.5713  1.23959
   86  443    69.4142  1.23894
   87  449    70.2572  1.23831
   88  457    71.1012  1.23767
   89  461    71.9447  1.23706
   90  463    72.7872  1.23648
   91  467    73.6295  1.23592
   92  479    74.4736  1.23534
   93  487    75.3185  1.23476
   94  491    76.1631  1.23419
   95  499    77.0084  1.23363
   96  503    77.8533  1.23309
   97  509    78.6984  1.23255
   98  521    79.5452  1.232
   99  523    80.3912  1.23148
  100  541    81.2403  1.23092
  101  547    82.0896  1.23036
  102  557    82.9399  1.22981
  103  563    83.7903  1.22926
  104  569    84.6409  1.22872
  105  571    85.4905  1.22821
  106  577    86.3403  1.2277
  107  587    87.1911  1.22719
  108  593    88.042  1.22669
  109  599    88.893  1.22619
  110  601    89.7432  1.22572
  111  607    90.5934  1.22525
  112  613    91.4438  1.2248
  113  617    92.2938  1.22435
  114  619    93.1431  1.22392
  115  631    93.9937  1.22349
  116  641    94.8452  1.22304
  117  643    95.696  1.22262
  118  647    96.5465  1.22221
  119  653    97.3971  1.2218
  120  659    98.2477  1.2214
  121  661    99.0977  1.22102
  122  673    99.9489  1.22062
  123  677    100.8  1.22024
  124  683    101.651  1.21986
  125  691    102.502  1.21949
  126  701    103.354  1.21911
  127  709    104.207  1.21873
  128  719    105.061  1.21834
  129  727    105.914  1.21796
  130  733    106.768  1.21759
  131  739    107.622  1.21722
  132  743    108.476  1.21686
  133  751    109.33  1.2165
  134  757    110.184  1.21615
  135  761    111.038  1.2158
  136  769    111.892  1.21546
  137  773    112.746  1.21512
  138  787    113.601  1.21478
  139  797    114.457  1.21443
  140  809    115.314  1.21408
  141  811    116.17  1.21373
  142  821    117.027  1.21339
  143  823    117.884  1.21306
  144  827    118.74  1.21274
  145  829    119.595  1.21242
  146  839    120.451  1.21211
  147  853    121.309  1.21179
  148  857    122.166  1.21147
  149  859    123.022  1.21116
  150  863    123.878  1.21087
  151  877    124.736  1.21056
  152  881    125.593  1.21026
  153  883    126.449  1.20997
  154  887    127.306  1.20969
  155  907    128.164  1.20939
  156  911    129.022  1.2091
  157  919    129.88  1.20881
  158  929    130.739  1.20851
  159  937    131.598  1.20822
  160  941    132.457  1.20794
  161  947    133.316  1.20766
  162  953    134.175  1.20738
  163  967    135.035  1.2071
  164  971    135.894  1.20682
  165  977    136.754  1.20655
  166  983    137.613  1.20628
  167  991    138.473  1.20601
  168  997    139.333  1.20574
jagy@phobeusjunior:~$
```