# What Is the Growth Rate of a Primorial?

Tags: calculus, primorial

As the title says, what is the growth rate of a primorial? I'm trying to evaluate the execution and data requirements of a function that uses one.

Thanks!

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2182325/how-does-one-know-the-growth-rate-of-distinct-prime-divisors/2182348 This may help.

Comment: Closely related: [Is there a better upper bound for the primorial...](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/450525/is-there-a-better-upper-bound-for-the-primorial-x-than-4x)

Comment: @高田航: The link you give is for a Question about number of distinct prime divisors.  Does this connect in some way to the growth of primorials?